# How to get CPU(idle) value in the vmstat result

Tags: awk

I am trying to get the value of 'id' in the vmstat result.
However, I found out that the position of 'id' column is different between platforms such as linux/AIX/HP...

```
## Linux
procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- --system-- -----cpu------
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa st
 0  0  35268 117568 158244 1849104    0    0     3 11321    5    2  9 15 73  3  0
```

So, I think I should find the string 'id' and get the position(the) then, get the value of the position in the next row.

How can I do that with awk script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this oneliner does what you want:

```
awk '{for(i=NF;i>0;i--)if($i=="id"){x=i;break}}END{print $x}'
```

first find out the `id` index, then print the corresponding column in the last line.